# Python contour polar plot from discrete data

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I wonder if the rectangular and polar contour plots may be drawn in this case.
The sample data may be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gth3fhgy4otccx/data.csv?dl=1).

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read data
# https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gth3fhgy4otccx/data.csv?dl=1
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
# initiate figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
# plot scatter
ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, c=df.value, marker='+', cmap='hsv')

# add polar axis
ax = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='polar')
# plot scatter
ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, c=df.value, marker='+', cmap='hsv')
```

... and the rectangular & polar scatter plots look like:
I would like to get the contour plots instead.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For data that isn't organized as a regular grid, `ax.tricontourf()` would create a contour plot based on a triangulation.

To get a polar plot, `tricontourf` could be called with the values transformed from polar to Cartesian coordinates. To show the polar grid, polar axes can be created at the same position.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))

ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.tricontourf(df.x, df.y, df.value, levels=256, cmap='hsv')

ax = fig.add_subplot(122)
theta = np.radians(df.x)
rad = df.y
ax.tricontourf(rad * np.cos(theta), rad * np.sin(theta), df.value, levels=256, cmap='hsv')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.axis('off')

ax_polar = fig.add_axes(ax.get_position(), polar=True)
ax_polar.set_facecolor('none') # make transparent
ax_polar.set_ylim(0, rad.max())

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

With `levels=50` it looks like:

[image: 50 levels]